# Thread safety and System.Text.Encoding in C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Is it safe to use the same `Encoding` object from different threads?

By "using" I mean, calling `Encoding.GetString()`, `Encoding.GetBytes()` and write some XML with an `XmlWriter` (created by something like `XmlWriter.Create(myStream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = myEncoding })`.

The msdn site states that "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe".

So, how can I safely write two XML documents concurrently? (thank you!!)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe to use the same `Encoding` object, as it's designed to be stateless - whereas [`Encoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.aspx) and [`Decoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder.aspx) are stateful, maintaining incomplete characters etc if necessary. I suppose you *could* write a stateful `Encoding` class, but it would be a really bad idea. As far as I'm aware, all of the built-in encoding implementations are stateless and thread-safe.

For example, the `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.ASCII` etc properties are singletons.

Comment: Thank you!! I just wanted to be sure because but couldn't find a confirmation elsewhere.

Comment: Is it though?  The static properties on `Encoding` are thread-safe, but that doesn't imply that the objects exposed by those properties are thread-safe.  I'm in a situation where I have to encode a *large* number of strings in parallel and I don't want to create tons of instances of the `Utf8Encoding` instance.

Comment: @casperOne: Two questions: 1) Do you know that `Encoding.UTF8` actually gives a new encoding each time; 2) Have you actually *measured* whether it would be a problem to create a new instance each time even if it does?

Comment: @JonSkeet 1) It's an implementation detail, but no, `Encoding.UTF8` does *not* give a new instance every time (Reflector or any such tool will show you that).  2) In my case, yes, I'm encoding millions of string segments together in parallel.  I'm shingling documents for the purposes of minhashing and creating a new instance every time is incredibly wasteful/inefficient.  I don't want byte order marks to be emitted, so using the `Encoding.UTF8` prevents me from using that instance.  Even if I did use the instance, the question of thread-safety for an instance arises.

Comment: @casperOne: Well if UTF8Encoding weren't thread-safe, `Encoding.UTF8` couldn't return the same instance every time, could it? Unless it create a "special" instance to be particularly thread-safe. Basically, by design `Encoding` is stateless and thread-safe, whereas `Encoder` and `Decoder` aren't. You still haven't shown that you actually *measured* the cost of creating a new instance each time. Sure, you're encoding millions of strings. That sounds like potentially quite a bit of work. Are you sure that creating *one* extra object for each of those encoding operations would be significant?

Comment: @JonSkeet The documentation explicitly excludes any thread safety guarantees of `Encoding` instances: `Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.` Both for `Encoding` and for `UTF8Encoding`. This boilerplate may be due to lazy copy-and-paste. But I'm facing the same situation as casperOne, and the documentation does not make me feel like creating a `UTF8Encoding` singleton and using it across threads, although I agree that `Encoding`s feel stateless, even though the docs aren't explicit about that it.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: Feel free to create a new instance per thread if you really want, but I'm still utterly convinced that `Encoding` objects are *actually* thread-safe (or rather, the .NET implementations are and if you write your own derived class I'd urge you to make it thread-safe too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Agree. I ended up sharing a non-BOM-UTF8Encoding singleton, although it means relying on the current implementation rather than the documentation=specification. In general not the safest thing to do, but - just as with the memory model guarantees added (in 3.0?) to not break the oft-used double-checked locking idiom - I guess MS would risk too many complaints if they made it thread-unsafe in the future.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: Indeed. There are all kinds of things which aren't actually documented - IIRC, the order in which values come out of a `List<T>` via `GetEnumerator` isn't (or wasn't) documented, but obviously everyone relies on that...